# Why FindFunction can't Find the Partial Date in the Range - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Refer below code. `find` function not find the partial date in the range.i knew that we can use `for loop` to find the partial date in the range but why `find` function doesn't work for finding the partial date?   The question is simple but i can't find the answer in google...

```
Sub Demo()

Dim day As Long
Dim monthYear As String
Dim ws As Range


    monthYear = Right(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10"), 7) ' monthYear = 08-2017
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D30")

    Set c = ws.Find(monthYear, Lookat:=xlPart)

End Sub
```

`ws` Range

```
11-01-2016
29-02-2016
28-03-2016
27-04-2016
27-05-2016
27-06-2016
29-08-2016
29-08-2016
27-09-2016
27-10-2016
28-11-2016
27-12-2016
27-01-2017
27-02-2017
27-03-2017
27-04-2017
29-05-2017
27-06-2017
13-08-2017
28-08-2017
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the `monthYear`variable is a string, but the range is set as "Date" format, so it is trying to find a string in a date, and failing. Can you check this? If I format the range as text it works for me.

Comment: @Moacir thank u for your suggestion i changed the range as text format but whole range value converted as numbers

Comment: I've just tried this where my cell format is date format (`dd-mm-yyyy`) and I have a string format variable and it works fine for me. I suspect your problem may be in your `monthYear`. Can you `TRIM` your `monthYear` and confirm that your `monthYear` value is **08-2017**. Also, don't forget to change the column format back to `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
monthYear = Right(CStr(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10")), 7)
```

Try to run this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim rngCell as Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("D3:D30")
        If Year(rngCell) = 2017 Then
            Debug.Print rngCell.Address
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Then rebuild the logic, using the `Year()`.

Concerning the `Find()`, try building something small like this one:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim rngRange    As Range
    Set rngRange = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("08.2016")
    Debug.Print rngRange.Address
End Sub
```

It should work.

Comment: Try formatting the dates as text. Or see the edit, @Ashok.

Comment: thank u for your suggestion dude - i know the for loop concept but my question is why find function not working

Comment: @Ashok - working with `Text` format is not the best idea. Try using the `Year()`.

Comment: i know the for loop concept but my question is why find function not working for partial date even thoug converted as string

Comment: Nothing happening dude

Comment: @Ashok - open a new Excel file, write `10.08.2016`, format it as text and give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

This code transforms the Date to search in `Long` to make a loop through the month and then is converted back to `Date`.
So it loops a find through a whole month (slow).

If you have a huge workbook, It is not recommended.

```
Sub Demo()

Dim monthYear As Date
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, cellFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 4), ws.Cells(lastrow, 4))

    monthYear = (Right(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10"), 7)) ' monthYear = 08-2017
    intDaysInMonth = day(DateSerial(Year(monthYear), Month(monthYear) + 1, 0))

    For i = 0 To intDaysInMonth - 1
        LookingFor = CLng(monthYear) + i
        LookingForString = CStr(CDate(LookingFor))
        With rng
            Set cellFound = .Find(what:=LookingForString, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
                    Do
                        Debug.Print cellFound.Address
                        Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
                    Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
                 End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

It is messy and there are better ways to optimize it. I think you were receiving error 13: Type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to use the Find function with XlValues in the lookin parameter to search for a string value in a dates range.

The cells numberformat property must then be a date format other than the default date format.

It is also important to ensure that the width of the columns is large enough to avoid the dates being replaced by #####.

You could use something like this :

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10").NumberFormat = "d-m-yyyy"
t = Split(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Text, "-")
monthYear = t(1) & "-" & t(2)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D30")
ws.NumberFormat = "d-m-yyyy"
Set c = ws.Find(monthYear, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
```